# VMa <- Ma, VMb -> Ma   ...Versus...   VMa <- VMb -> Ma

Tags: .net, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

*Option1: ViewModelA <- ModelA , ViewModelB -> ModelA*
*Option2: ViewModelA <- ViewModelB -> ModelA*

**ModelA* changes its properties **only** through *ViewModelB* so in *Option2* it doesn't need to implement any mechanism to inform anyone in the viemodel that it has changed.
**Option2* needs a messaging solution between the two viewmodels whereas *Option1* doesn't.

Which is better, *Option1* or *Option2* ?

**EDIT :**
I chose to implement *Option2*, since I wanted to keep *ModelA* class a simple POCO.
I also renamed *ViewModelB* to *ModelViewB*.

**ASWER :**
Finally implemented ... Option1. The **temptation** here was that I could keep *ModelA* simple (eg without notifying anyone). But in the end it complicated the application, since it was a departure from the other classes' implementations. Better to keep and follow one rule (even maybe with some overhead).

The *messenger* classes actually are helper classes, and not so much a core ingredient of the pattern, so I kept the solution more close to the pattern (as the guys below also mentioned).

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about your scenario? Do you have two GUIs, one that will change the model and the other won't?

Comment: @jpsstavares Exactly.The one of the two GUIs is only for presentation purposes (actually some shapes drawn on canvas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always go with the first option.

This option is the one that follows the MVVM and the one that produces and architecture that is cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: oops! please recheck the arrows. I made a mistake. The two direction is one direction arrow. Thanks!

Comment: It still is closer to the original MVVM pattern. And don't forget that your need can change in the future and you may need to change the model from both ViewModels or both ViewModels be updated from the Model.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `Mediator` implemented as part of your MVVM structure (MVVM + M). Option 1 will work fine. It will be very good time invested, if you add the mediator pattern to your structure for the future.

As long as no data is directly accessed from the view and all data is accessed through the viewmodel, may it be gets or set, then it is fine.

Comment: Actually I use a messenger class from MVVM Foundation, for some other communication puproses, so my question is not exactly that. It is more like which is "philospically" correct between the two.

Comment: Okay Option 1 is fine. I do the same thing in a part of my application. You don't need to have a messaging structure in between. The rule is simple. As long as your View is not setting or getting information directly it is fine. If you would snap on a Silverlight View, it should work with out you changing anything in the ViewModels. Hope i answered your question.

Comment: oops! please recheck the arrows. I made a mistake. The two direction is one direction arrow. Thanks!